# Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing ( not a Dev Tools or logger problem)

Tags: redux, react-redux

I tried to disable Redux dev tools and logger and its not a dev tools or logger problem. Tried changing the order of middleware and also does not work.

**Action**

```
export const authUser = (userData) => dispatch => {
const dataQ = function getFormData(object) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => formData.append(key, object[key]));
    return formData;
}

const dataAuth = {
    wh_country_code : 'US',
    token : userData.accessToken,
    social : 'facebook'

}

dispatch({
    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFULL',
    payload : userData
})

fetch('http://localhost/api/user/auth', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataQ(dataAuth)
  }).then( response => {

      if(response.status == 200) {
        console.log(response.status)

      } else {
    // POST to register user if user dont exist
        fetch('http://localhost/api/user/register/facebook', {
            method: 'POST',
            body : dataQ(dataReg)

        })
       }
   })}
```

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Facebook from 'react-facebook-login';
import Google from 'react-google-login';
import socialStyle from '../../css/Components/Account_public/Social.css';
import history from '../../history'
import store from '../../store'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { authUser } from '../../actions/authActions'

/*const googleStyle = {

background: `#db4437`,
marginTop: `20px`,
border: `1px solid #db4437`,
maxWidth: `165px`,
height: `45px`,
position: `relative`,
fontSize: `20px`,
fontWeight: `normal`,
lineHeight: `1.48`,
letterSpacing:` -0.5px`,
textAlign:` left`,
color: `#ffffff`,
top:`-114px`,
left:`24px`
}*/

class Social extends React.Component{
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        userID: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        picture: '',
        token : '',
        wh_country_code : 'US',
        social : 'facebook',
    }
    this.responseFacebook = this.responseFacebook.bind(this);
    this.responseGoogle = this.responseGoogle.bind(this);
}

responseFacebook  (response)  {
     // Split name that Facebook object returns into "first_name", and "last_name"
    var fullName = response.name;
    var index = fullName.indexOf(" ");
    var first_name = fullName.substr(0, index);
    var last_name = fullName.substr(index + 1);
    // Authentication (Login) data sent to API

    // Registration data sent to API
    const dataReg = {
        token : response.accessToken,
        wh_country_code : 'US',
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email : response.email,
    }

    this.props.authUser(response)
    // POST to authenticate user
    /* fetch('http://localhost/api/user/auth', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataQ(dataAuth)
  }).then( response => {
      if(response.status == 200) {

      } else {
        // POST to register user if user dont exist
        fetch('http://localhost/api/user/register/facebook', {
            method: 'POST',
            body : dataQ(dataReg)

        })
      }
  }) */

}


responseGoogle (response) {
    // Function to convert data from JSON to FormData
    const dataQ = function getFormData(object) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        Object.keys(object).forEach(key => formData.append(key, 
 object[key]));
        return formData;
    }
            // Register with google parameters
    const googleReg = {
        first_name : response.profileObj.givenName,
        last_name : response.profileObj.familyName,
        email : response.profileObj.email,
        token : response.accessToken,
        wh_country_code : 'US'
    }
    // Auth with google parameters
    const googleAuth =  {
        token : response.accessToken,
        wh_country_code : 'US',
        social: 'google'
    }


    fetch('http://localhost/api/user/auth', {
        method : 'POST',
        BODY : dataQ(googleAuth)
    }).then(response => {
        if(response.status == 200) {
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true
            })


        } else {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn : false
            })
            fetch('http://localhost/api/user/register/google', {
                method : 'POST',
                body : dataQ(googleReg)
            })
        }
    })
}

logout() {
    fetch('http://localhost/api/user/logout', {
        method : "POST",
    })
    this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: false,
        accessToken : '',
    })
}

render(){
    var divstyle = {
        color: 'red',
        fontWeight: '600'
    }
    let fbContent;
    let googleContent;
    let dragica = '1'
    if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
        fbContent = null;
    } else {
            fbContent = (
                <Facebook
                    appId="111232816261"
                    autoLoad={false}
                    fields="name,email,picture"
                    onClick={this.componentClicked}
                    callback={this.responseFacebook}
                    textButton="Facebook"
                    cssClass="facebook-btn"
                    />

            );
    }

    if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
        googleContent = null;
    } else {
            googleContent = (
                <Google
                    clientId="426090696509-g9qgpjjrtf4b4d3tuqarslp3na4ehufp.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                    buttonText="Google"
                    onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
                    onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
                    className="google-btn"
                />
            );
    }

    return(
        <div className="SocialLoginWrap">
                {fbContent}
                {googleContent}
        </div>
    );
}

}




Social.propTypes = {
authUser : PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default withRouter(connect(null, { authUser })(Social));
```

**Reducer**

```
import history from '../history'
const initialState = {
isLoggedIn : false,
}
const authReducer = (state= initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFULL':
     history.push('/')
     return {
         state : true,
         payload : action.payload
     }

    case 'LOGIN_FAILED':
     alert('Failed login idiot')

    case 'LOGOUT': 
     history.push('/account')   
     return null
    default:
     return null
}
}


export default authReducer
```

If anyone has any suggestions please say, im stuck on this problem for days now. I tried lot of stuff and same error pops up. Full error description :

```
sdk.js:108 Uncaught Error: You may not call store.getState() while the 
reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an 
 argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the 
store.
    at Object.getState (redux.js:114)
    at Object.runComponentSelector [as run] (connectAdvanced.js:37)
    at Connect.componentWillReceiveProps (connectAdvanced.js:168)
    at callComponentWillReceiveProps (react-dom.development.js:12564)
    at updateClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12774)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14262)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15082)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:17820)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:17860)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:17946)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the issue, but you definitely shouldn't be calling `history.push()` in a reducer.  In fact, try removing that and see what happens.  Also, what specific sequence of steps are you doing that leads up to this error?

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question. If you can remove any of it that is not needed for your question, this will help other users provide better answers.

Comment: @markerikson That solved my issue, thank you so much man!

Comment: Yep, that was likely causing other actions or UI behavior to kick in, which then dispatched more actions.  Stuff like that `history.push()` counts as a "side effect", and you're not supposed to do any side effects in a Redux reducer - they should only return updated state values.  If you want to cause side effects based on dispatched actions, you should do that in a middleware instead.

Comment: @markerikson I understand now, im relatively new to Redux and i try to implement it on my job, its my first job also so this is much appreciated, thank you!